# If condition to determine which stored procedures to create

Tags: sql-server

This is more than just checking for existence

I have a script that creates 27 stored procedures.  I need to run this script against two databases.  The second database only needs 25 of the 27 stored procedures.  I was hoping to wrap my code in an if statement to determine the current db

Pseudo Example:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [A]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[A]
    @CountryCode CHAR(3),
    @LanguageCode CHAR(3) = NULL,   
AS
BEGIN
...

GO

IF (DB_NAME() <> 'DB2')
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [B]
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[B]
        @CountryCode CHAR(3),
        @LanguageCode CHAR(3) = NULL,   
    AS
    BEGIN
    ...

    GO

    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [C]
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[C]
        @CountryCode CHAR(3),
        @LanguageCode CHAR(3) = NULL,   
    AS
    BEGIN
    ...
    GO
END
```

I know I can wrap it in an `EXEC` for scope but at that point I might as well create a new file.  I have seen the older questions, but I didn't know if there was anything new in SQL Server 2016/2019 to address this.

Comment: You mean that first find the DB name and then create the proper SPs?

Comment: I'm not sure that will work because of the GOs in between. Each of the GO will create a distinct executable batch that gets run. If anything, my guess is that you'll get a syntax error either about an unclosed BEGIN or an END with no BEGIN, and you'll still end up with SProcs where you don't want them. 
I could be wrong though. But I'm not sure that it's going to work the way you want it to... at least not like that. You would have to wrap it up into a string, and execute the string (probably more than one). and then wrap those commands into your  if...begin...end block.

Comment: Yes I received an error like Begin not External

Comment: @cdrrr Basically If you are not this one DB don't create Stored Proc B and C

Answer (score 1):

I would use pattern like below 1) First create all SPs 2) Drop specific ones:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE proc1 ...
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE proc2 ...
GO
...

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE proc27 ...
GO

IF (DB_NAME() <> 'DB2') DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc26;
IF (DB_NAME() <> 'DB2') DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc27;
```

Comment: Interesting solution - for my case it would not work because I get errors if I try to create the sp